# Алгоритм выпадения случайной вещи

Tags: php

Добрый день! Недавно возник вопрос, как реализован алгоритм выпадения вещей на всяких сs go рулетках, там где открывают ящики с вещами? Мучает он меня уже несколько дней, так и не могу понять, как это может работать. Кто что знает? Направьте пожалуйста туда, где можно об этом почитать.

Самый простой вариант как по мне вот такой:

1. Берем определенное кол-во типов вещей(в зависимости от их цены) к
   примеру их оказалось у нас 3
2. По ценам 1 - 10р  , 2 - 25, 3 - 140р.
3. Устанавливаем цену для одной попытки открытия к примеру цена 20 р.
4. Теперь можно составить из них какую-то последовательность, к примеру положить их в массив да так чтобы вещей с типом 1 было например 100 шт, вещей с типом 2 было 15 шт, а вещей с типом 3 - 2 шт.
5. Располагаем элементы последовательности в случайном порядке.
6. Когда пользователь открывает кейс, то генерируется псевдослучайное число.

Кажется этот вариант не так и плох, ведь увеличивая кол-во элементов цена которых дешевле чем цена открытия кейсов мы можем регулировать шанс выпадения вещей которые дороже. Но всегда есть вероятность того, что пользователь при первом открытии получит вещь с типом 3

Как убрать этот недостаток?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php 0_o ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, смешно

Comment: Вы пожалуйста по подробнее опешите что хотите

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Честно я не знаю как в php происходит random, но в обычных ЯП'ах оно получается на основе полученного времени, а точнее миллесекунд (или наносекундах, давно читал про это)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Исправил вопрос, я плохо излагаю мысли на "бумаге", но надеюсь так будет более понятно)

Comment: Чтобы сразу не выпала редкая вещь, можно сделать проверку, если она выпадает, перегенерировать число(но так делать некрасиво:) )

Comment: @erm, тоже как вариант)

Comment: Почему Вы считаете возможность выиграть редкую вещь с первой попытки недостатком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понял вас (вроде-бы :D), я когда-то тоже думал насчёт того как делать что-то редким в обычном рандоме, я короче придумал такой алгоритм (на мой взгляд проще не предумаешь) :

1. Взять 3 вещи
2. Сделать обычный `random` (например от 0 до 10, можно делать хоть какой диапазон)
3. Потом обычным `switch`'ем (или несколькими `if`'ами) сделать так :

   - если число от 0..5 то выпадает первая вещь
   - если от 5..8 то вторая (естественно которая дороже)
   - а если от 8..10 то самая дорогая

Профит... )

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы предлагается за счет сужения диапазонов, которые в switch'e регулировать редкость вещи?)

Comment: Угу, по моему в этом и заключается, простота работы и удобство этого мини-алгоритма :)

Comment: Кстати вот статья про которую я ввиду имел в самом начале "давно читал про это" --> https://exelab.ru/art/?action=view&id=136 (не реклама !!!), кстати очень интересная статья

Comment: Довольно неплохо, спасибо, статью почитаю)